# Magento2 : Update category, URL key already exists error

Tags: admin, updates, categories, magento2

I have created a new category and its not visible in navigation menu as of now.
I am adding products to it via code and its working.

Now i am editing the category to show in navigation menu, it throws error as "URL key for specified store already exists".

I tried to:
Unassigned products, throws same error.
Changed URL, left blank or changed value of URL.

Please let me know.

Comment: Same here... huge issue!

Comment: I have same issue, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Clear db table url_rewrite but! for categories only. otherwise it will mess with CMS pages links.

After doing this error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

1) delete records from "url_rewrite" where entity_type is "category"

2) run `php bin/magento php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

1) Going your Database

2) Search the `url_rewrite` and "category" `entity_type` is Remove

3) And Finally run this command, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Temporarily rename the category URL to something else, clear the cache and rename it to the original URL you had before.